# Unable to filter data Product Name wise in android

Tags: android

this is my adapter class:

```
 public class Searchlistviewadapter extends ArrayAdapter<DataModel> implements
            Filterable {

        // Declare Variables
        Context context;
        LayoutInflater inflater;
        ArrayList<DataModel> datamodel;
        ArrayList<DataModel> productlist;
        private ProductFilter filter;
        private SparseBooleanArray mSelectedItemsIds;

        MyDatabaseHelper dbhelper;
        int counter;
        int Quantity = 0;
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> hashMap;
        int searchBy = 0;
        static final String TAG = "LISTT";
        List<DataModel> listDatamodels = new ArrayList<DataModel>();

        public Searchlistviewadapter(Context context, int resourceId,
                ArrayList<DataModel> worldpopulationlist) {
            super(context, resourceId, worldpopulationlist);
            mSelectedItemsIds = new SparseBooleanArray();
            this.context = context;
            this.datamodel = worldpopulationlist;

            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            dbhelper = new MyDatabaseHelper(context);

            productlist = worldpopulationlist;
            hashMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        }

        private class ViewHolder {
            TextView tv;
            TextView Quantity;
            TextView cost;
            ImageView img;
            ImageView plusitem;
            ImageView minusitem;
            TextView itemnumber;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
            final ViewHolder holder;
            if (view == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);
                //
                holder.tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                holder.img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                holder.Quantity = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);

                holder.cost = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

                view.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }
            // Capture position and set to the TextViews
            String rupee = context.getResources().getString(R.string.Rs);
            final MyDatabaseHelper dbManager = new MyDatabaseHelper(context);
            dbManager.open();

            holder.tv.setText(datamodel.get(position).getProductname());

            holder.Quantity.setText(datamodel.get(position).getProdcutQuantity());

            holder.cost.setText(rupee + datamodel.get(position).getProdcutCost());

            holder.img.setImageResource(datamodel.get(position).getProductimage());

            holder.plusitem = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
            holder.plusitem.setTag(position);
            holder.minusitem = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
            holder.minusitem.setTag(position);
            holder.itemnumber = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView4);

            holder.plusitem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    int index = Integer.parseInt(arg0.getTag().toString());
                    Log.e(TAG, Integer.toString(index));

                    int quantity;

                    if (hashMap.containsKey(index)) {
                        quantity = hashMap.get(index);
                    } else
                        quantity = 0;
                    quantity++;

                    hashMap.put(index, quantity);
                    holder.itemnumber.setText(quantity + "");
                    // holder.itemnumber.invalidate();
                    dbhelper.open();
                    String producttype = dbhelper.getCteogryusingId(datamodel.get(
                            position).getProdcutid());
                    dbManager.AddShopingItem(
                            datamodel.get(position).getProdcutid(), producttype,
                            datamodel.get(position).getProductname(), datamodel
                                    .get(position).getProdcutQuantity(), datamodel
                                    .get(position).getProdcutCost(), String
                                    .valueOf(datamodel.get(position)
                                            .getProductimage()), String
                                    .valueOf(quantity), "true");
                    sendBroadcaset(true);

                }

            });
            holder.minusitem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    int index = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());
                    Log.e(TAG, Integer.toString(index));

                    int quantity;

                    if (hashMap.containsKey(index)) {
                        quantity = hashMap.get(index);
                    } else
                        quantity = 0;

                    quantity--;

                    if (quantity < 0)
                        quantity = 0;

                    hashMap.put(index, quantity);
                    holder.itemnumber.setText(quantity + "");
                    // holder.itemnumber.invalidate();
                    dbhelper.open();
                    String producttype = dbhelper.getCteogryusingId(datamodel.get(
                            position).getProdcutid());
                    dbManager.AddShopingItem(
                            datamodel.get(position).getProdcutid(), producttype,
                            datamodel.get(position).getProductname(), datamodel
                                    .get(position).getProdcutQuantity(), datamodel
                                    .get(position).getProdcutCost(), String
                                    .valueOf(datamodel.get(position)
                                            .getProductimage()), String
                                    .valueOf(quantity), "true");
                    sendBroadcaset(false);
                }
            });
            return view;
        }

        private void sendBroadcaset(boolean b) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(
                    new Intent("update_boolean_variable").putExtra("action", b));
        }

        private class ProductFilter extends Filter {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint != null && constraint.toString().length() > 0) {
                    ArrayList<DataModel> filteredItems = new ArrayList<DataModel>();

                    for (int i = 0, l = datamodel.size(); i < l; i++) {
                        DataModel country = datamodel.get(i);
                        if (country.getProductname().toString().toLowerCase()
                                .contains(constraint))
                            filteredItems.add(country);
                    }
                    result.count = filteredItems.size();
                    result.values = filteredItems;

                } else {
                    synchronized (this) {
                        result.values = datamodel;
                        result.count = datamodel.size();
                    }
                }

                return result;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                    FilterResults results) {
                productlist = (ArrayList<DataModel>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                clear();
                for (int i = 0, l = productlist.size(); i < l; i++)
                    add(productlist.get(i));

                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            if (filter == null) {
                filter = new ProductFilter();
            }
            return filter;
        }
    }
```

this is my activity claSS:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    ImageView backbutton;
    private ListView lv;
    Searchlistviewadapter listviewadapter;
    EditText inputSearch;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList;
    MyDatabaseHelper dbhelper;
    public static final int img2 = R.drawable.asirwadatata;
    public static final int img3 = R.drawable.asirwadatata;
    public static final int img4 = R.drawable.asirwadatata;
    public static final int img5 = R.drawable.asirwadatata;
    public static final int img6 = R.drawable.asirwadatata;
    public static final int img7 = R.drawable.asirwadatata;
    ArrayList<DataModel> lstDataModel;

    public static final int[] images = new int[] { img2, img3, img4, img5,
            img6, img7 };

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dbhelper = new MyDatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
        dbhelper.open();
        String ProductId[] = dbhelper.getAllProductID();

        dbhelper.open();

        String products[] = dbhelper.getAllProductName();

        dbhelper.open();
        String productsquant[] = dbhelper.getAllProductQuntity();
        dbhelper.open();
        String productcost[] = dbhelper.getAllProductCost();

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

        lstDataModel = new ArrayList<DataModel>();

        for (int i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
            DataModel datamodel = new DataModel();
            datamodel.setProdcutid(ProductId[i]);
            datamodel.setProductname(products[i]);
            datamodel.setProdcutQuantity(productsquant[i]);
            datamodel.setProdcutCost(productcost[i]);
            datamodel.setProductimage(images[i]);
            lstDataModel.add(datamodel);
        }

        listviewadapter = new Searchlistviewadapter(MainActivity.this,
                R.layout.listitem, lstDataModel);

        lv.setAdapter(listviewadapter);

        /**
         * Enabling Search Filter
         * */
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                System.out.println("Text [" + cs + "]");
                listviewadapter.getFilter().filter(cs.toString());

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                    int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
}
```

DataModel:

```
public class DataModel {

    public String getProdcutid() {
        return prodcutid;
    }

    public void setProdcutid(String prodcutid) {
        this.prodcutid = prodcutid;
    }

    private String prodcutid;

    private String Cateogry;
    private String Productname;
    private String ProdcutQuantity;
    private int Productimage;
    private String ProdcutCost;
    private String NuberofProductQuantity;
    public String eachProdcutcount;

    public String getEachProdcutcount() {
        return eachProdcutcount;
    }

    public void setEachProdcutcount(String eachProdcutcount) {
        this.eachProdcutcount = eachProdcutcount;
    }

    public DataModel() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public DataModel(String productname, String prodcutQuantity,
            int productimage) {
        super();
        this.Productname = productname;
        this.ProdcutQuantity = prodcutQuantity;
        this.Productimage = productimage;
    }

    public String getCateogry() {
        return Cateogry;
    }

    public void setCateogry(String cateogry) {
        Cateogry = cateogry;
    }

    public String getProductname() {
        return Productname;
    }

    public void setProductname(String productname) {
        Productname = productname;
    }

    public String getProdcutQuantity() {
        return ProdcutQuantity;
    }

    public void setProdcutQuantity(String prodcutQuantity) {
        ProdcutQuantity = prodcutQuantity;
    }

    public int getProductimage() {
        return Productimage;
    }

    public void setProductimage(int productimage) {
        Productimage = productimage;
    }

    public String getProdcutCost() {
        return ProdcutCost;
    }

    public void setProdcutCost(String prodcutCost) {
        ProdcutCost = prodcutCost;
    }

    public String getNuberofProductQuantity() {
        return NuberofProductQuantity;
    }

    public void setNuberofProductQuantity(String nuberofProductQuantity) {
        NuberofProductQuantity = nuberofProductQuantity;
    }
```

i am trying to filter or Search item from Listview i am able to filter data But Problem when i clear data i mean when we blank data after filtering from Edit text then my listview item becomes blank again we have launch app and then item listview item becomes visible please tell me where am doing wrong please suggest me .

Comment: Your list gets empty..because you are making refrence productlist = worldpopulationlist; at this line...

Comment: then what we have to do here ?> @MeenalSharma

Comment: replace this line with productlist=ArrayList<DataModel>;productlist.addAll(worldpopulationlist)..

Comment: where in constructor?@MeenalSharma

Comment: yes..in constructor..or at every place..where you are copying data from one list to another use addAll()

Comment: productlist.addAll(worldpopulationlist);  when i try to add in constructor it show excetion null pointer exception

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95200/discussion-between-departure-and-meenal-sharma).

Comment: do not use `ArrayAdapter`, use `SimpleCursorAdapter` + `FilterQueryProvider` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed your adapter class ..please try with below class

```
public class Searchlistviewadapter extends ArrayAdapter<DataModel> implements
    Filterable {

// Declare Variables
Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
ArrayList<DataModel> datamodel;
ArrayList<DataModel> productlist;
private ProductFilter filter;
private SparseBooleanArray mSelectedItemsIds;

MyDatabaseHelper dbhelper;
int counter;
int Quantity = 0;
HashMap<Integer, Integer> hashMap;
int searchBy = 0;
static final String TAG = "LISTT";
List<DataModel> listDatamodels = new ArrayList<DataModel>();

public Searchlistviewadapter(Context context, int resourceId,
        ArrayList<DataModel> worldpopulationlist) {
    super(context, resourceId, worldpopulationlist);
    mSelectedItemsIds = new SparseBooleanArray();
    this.context = context;
    // this.datamodel = worldpopulationlist;
    this.datamodel = new ArrayList<DataModel>();
    // productlist = worldpopulationlist;
    this.datamodel.addAll(worldpopulationlist);
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    dbhelper = new MyDatabaseHelper(context);
    productlist = new ArrayList<DataModel>();
    // productlist = worldpopulationlist;
    productlist.addAll(worldpopulationlist);
    hashMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView tv;
    TextView Quantity;
    TextView cost;
    ImageView img;
    ImageView plusitem;
    ImageView minusitem;
    TextView itemnumber;
}

public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (view == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);
        //
        holder.tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        holder.Quantity = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        holder.cost = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    // Capture position and set to the TextViews
    String rupee = context.getResources().getString(R.string.Rs);
    final MyDatabaseHelper dbManager = new MyDatabaseHelper(context);
    dbManager.open();

    holder.tv.setText(datamodel.get(position).getProductname());

    holder.Quantity.setText(datamodel.get(position).getProdcutQuantity());

    holder.cost.setText(rupee + datamodel.get(position).getProdcutCost());

    holder.img.setImageResource(datamodel.get(position).getProductimage());

    holder.plusitem = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    holder.plusitem.setTag(position);
    holder.minusitem = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    holder.minusitem.setTag(position);
    holder.itemnumber = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView4);

    holder.plusitem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            int index = Integer.parseInt(arg0.getTag().toString());
            Log.e(TAG, Integer.toString(index));

            int quantity;

            if (hashMap.containsKey(index)) {
                quantity = hashMap.get(index);
            } else
                quantity = 0;
            quantity++;

            hashMap.put(index, quantity);
            holder.itemnumber.setText(quantity + "");
            // holder.itemnumber.invalidate();
            dbhelper.open();
            String producttype = dbhelper.getCteogryusingId(datamodel.get(
                    position).getProdcutid());
            dbManager.AddShopingItem(
                    datamodel.get(position).getProdcutid(), producttype,
                    datamodel.get(position).getProductname(), datamodel
                            .get(position).getProdcutQuantity(), datamodel
                            .get(position).getProdcutCost(), String
                            .valueOf(datamodel.get(position)
                                    .getProductimage()), String
                            .valueOf(quantity), "true");
            sendBroadcaset(true);

        }

    });
    holder.minusitem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int index = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());
            Log.e(TAG, Integer.toString(index));

            int quantity;

            if (hashMap.containsKey(index)) {
                quantity = hashMap.get(index);
            } else
                quantity = 0;

            quantity--;

            if (quantity < 0)
                quantity = 0;

            hashMap.put(index, quantity);
            holder.itemnumber.setText(quantity + "");
            // holder.itemnumber.invalidate();
            dbhelper.open();
            String producttype = dbhelper.getCteogryusingId(datamodel.get(
                    position).getProdcutid());
            dbManager.AddShopingItem(
                    datamodel.get(position).getProdcutid(), producttype,
                    datamodel.get(position).getProductname(), datamodel
                            .get(position).getProdcutQuantity(), datamodel
                            .get(position).getProdcutCost(), String
                            .valueOf(datamodel.get(position)
                                    .getProductimage()), String
                            .valueOf(quantity), "true");
            sendBroadcaset(false);
        }
    });
    return view;
}

private void sendBroadcaset(boolean b) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(
            new Intent("update_boolean_variable").putExtra("action", b));
}

private class ProductFilter extends Filter {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults results = null;
        try {
            String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
            results = new FilterResults();
            List<DataModel> list = productlist;
            ArrayList<DataModel> nlist = new ArrayList<DataModel>();
            if (constraint != null && constraint.toString().length() > 0) {

                for (int i = 0; i < productlist.size(); i++) {
                    DataModel filterableString = list.get(i);
                    if (filterableString.getProductname().toString()
                            .toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {
                        nlist.add(filterableString);
                    }
                }
                results.values = nlist;
                results.count = nlist.size();
            } else {
                synchronized (this) {
                    results.values = datamodel;
                    results.count = datamodel.size();
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
            FilterResults results) {
        try {
            datamodel = (ArrayList<DataModel>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            clear();
            for (int i = 0, l = datamodel.size(); i < l; i++)
                add(datamodel.get(i));
            notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if (filter == null) {
        filter = new ProductFilter();
    }
    return filter;
}
}
```

Comment: i got mistake ...its in filter process..you are taking data from wrong list..and also assigning to wrong..please try with this code